# Find a conformal mapping from Q (in the picture) onto the upper half plane set D = {z: Im(z) > 0}

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

So I got stuck trying to find a conformal mapping from Q onto the upper half plane set D = {z: Im(z) > 0}.

I've ultimately arrived at the conclusion that maybe $w = z^3$ could work as the first step but I just can't figure out what it would transform Q into. I understand that I can say that $z = re^{it}$, where $r = 1$, and then $w = r^3 e^{i \cdot 3t}$, but it doesn't really help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to map Q to $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty, \alpha]$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. This can be realized by using the möbiustranform

T(z)=$\frac{iz+1}{z+i}$.

This möbiustranform should map Q onto $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,1]$.

Now use the translation $z\mapsto z-1,25$ to get to $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,-0,25]$. From there you use koebe's function to get to the unit disc and the cayley transform to finally get to the upper half plane.

Note how you get T: When you think in the RS. You would wish to have a möbiustransform T that "rotates the RS 90 degrees towards you", explicitly it should map:

$-i\mapsto\infty$;
$-1\mapsto -1$;
$i\mapsto 0$;
$1\mapsto 1$;

Using these information you get the T above.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I think $T(z) = \frac{i - z}{zi - 1}$ could work better though (maybe)

Comment: Yes that is definitely better! Thank you, I just corrected it.